# empty TableModel after instantiating

Tags: java

Newbie seeking help please :-)

I am working on a little project to get familiar with Java desktop development and Database connectivity.

Attached code gives me an empty TableModel after instantiating therefore no data displayed in the JFrame.
Test class is instantiated from the menue of the main window with `Test.showFrame();`.

```
package ...

import ...

public class Test extends JPanel {

    public Test() {
        initializePanel();
    }

    private void initializePanel() {

        // Creates an instance of TableModel
        CategoryTableModel tableModel = new CategoryTableModel();

        System.out.println(tableModel.getRowCount());
        // Creates an instance of JTable with a TableModel
        // as the constructor parameters.

        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void showFrame() {
        JPanel panel = new Test();
        panel.setOpaque(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class CategoryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Category> all = null;
        private Iterator<Category> iterator = null;
        private int tableRowCount;
        private TableModel tableModel;


        public CategoryTableModel(){
            Vector tableData = new Vector();
            // TableModel's column names
            Vector<String> tableHeaders = new Vector<String>();
            tableHeaders.add("Category");

            // Database call
            all = new ReadCategory().allCategories();
            // TableModel's data
            for(Object o : all) {
                Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
                all.forEach((n) -> row.add(new Category().getName()));
                tableData.add(row);
                System.out.println("row added");

            }
            tableRowCount = tableData.size();
            tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders);
            System.out.println(tableModel.getRowCount());
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Database call is fetching data via Hibernate and stores data in a .

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your tableModel in initializePanel and the one in the constructor for CategoryTableModel are different objects, so the one you have added to the JTable is empty.

Comment: thanks for your reply and explanation. M still learning though how can I fix that?

Comment: Don't create a new TableModel in your CategoryTableModel class, the class itself is a table model. Just call the methods of the class itself.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I got your point that the CategoryTableModel class itself is the model! So I removed the line tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders); in the CategoryTableModel class.

Comment: ... then in the initialze() method I create with "CategoryTableModel tableModel = new CategoryTableModel()" the model for the JTable but still the same. Appreciate if you could elaborate your reply. I am still a newbie...

Comment: I will try later but I'm at work at the moment, so no time.

Comment: I've added an answer, if anything is not clear please say and I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its most basic form a table model for a JTable defines the columns, the mapping of object to column and holds the data for the JTable to call upon. If we take your current table model and cut it down to fit this basic requirement we get the following.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class CategoryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

  private final List<Category> tableData = new ArrayList<>();

  public void add(Category cat) {
    tableData.add(cat);

    fireTableDataChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public String getColumnName(int column) {
    String result = "";

    if (column == 0) {
      result = "Category Name";
    }

    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public int getRowCount() {
    return tableData.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getColumnCount() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
      return tableData.get(rowIndex).getName();
    }

    return null;
  }

}
```

Notice that we do not define any data in the model itself. All we define is some storage for the data and the column name of the single column that we require.

I have added an add() method that allows you to add data to the model (you may wish to define remove etc. yourself). When you add or remove data from the model you must always let the JTable know that the data has changed by calling fireTableDataChanged() so that the table can redraw itself.

To use this table model you will need to do

```
CategoryTableModel model = new CategoryTableModel();

model.add(new Category());

JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

You can replace the model.add() with a loop that iterates over your data and adds it to the model.

Comment: thanks, have been trough again and could correct my mistake.